# Hana SQL SAP DSP , can't use standard functions

Tags: sql, hana, sap

I am about to use standard functions and libraries of Hana Cloud SQL in the table function of SAP DSP. Looks like that none of these functions can be used.

For example, I would like to use the following function and DSP generates an error message :

```
DO
BEGIN

    USING SQLSCRIPT_STRING AS LIBRARY;
    
    DECLARE TEST_OUTPUT TABLE(RESULT NVARCHAR(5000));
    
    DECLARE TEST_STRING VARCHAR(50) := 'A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H';

    TEST_OUTPUT = LIBRARY:SPLIT_TO_TABLE(:TEST_STRING,',');
    
    SELECT * FROM :TEST_OUTPUT;

END
```

Is there a restriction for any Hana Cloud SQL standard functions in DSP?

Comment: SAP DSP = SAP Datasphere?